# Flow variables lose values

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow to create a new Lead and an appointment. At Lead's screen, there are some field validations, like not to exceed characters limits. When the validation occurs and returns to Lead's screen, fields like Name, Phone, Email, Url and Address lose their values and user has to re-enter them. However, this isn't happening at picklists, text, number fields.
I could use a text field instead of email field for example, but I will have to create new validations for email on text field.
Is there any other ideas how can I bypass this limitation?

Comment: can we see the flow?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding at screen's component value the value itself, for example {!Screen_Phone.value}